# Blender Height not divisible by 2

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I make an animation with ffmpeg video format (1280x1115) I did see this problem today. "Height not divisible by 2" [image]
and i find a solution. But i don't want to resize or scale my animation. If i don't use ffmpeg format my sounds are disappear on video with avi format. How can i fix it? Is there a any solution fro it?

Comment: In short you have to change the size. One pixel is not going to change anything in your animation.

Comment: one pixel? what is dimensions your mean? (1280x1114)?

Comment: Lol yes you are right! it works! thank you :))

Comment: yes that one. you could go 1280x1114, or 1280x1116